# (ArgumentError) unknown application: :bakeware

Tags: deployment, elixir

### Background

When trying to execute `mix release` on a Windows 11 machine for a Phoenix project I get the following error:

```
* assembling market_manager-2.1.5 on MIX_ENV=prod
* using config/runtime.exs to configure the release at runtime
←[32m* assembling←[39m bakeware market_manager

** (ArgumentError) unknown application: :bakeware
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/application.ex:1010: Application.app_dir/1
    (elixir 1.15.4) lib/application.ex:1041: Application.app_dir/2
    (bakeware 0.2.4) lib/bakeware/assembler.ex:71: Bakeware.Assembler.create_paths/1
    (bakeware 0.2.4) lib/bakeware/assembler.ex:83: Bakeware.Assembler.do_assemble/1
    (bakeware 0.2.4) lib/bakeware/assembler.ex:37: Bakeware.Assembler.assemble/1
    (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/tasks/release.ex:1064: Mix.Tasks.Release.run_steps/1
    (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/task.ex:447: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/5
    (mix 1.15.4) lib/mix/cli.ex:92: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

I am using PowerShell with Admin privileges and I have set the following env variables:

```
$env:CC="gcc"
$env:MAKE="make"
$env:MIX_ENV="prod"
```

I have installed all the dependencies via choco with `choco install -y zstandard make mingw`.

Further, here are my system settings:

```
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
OS build    22621.2283
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22662.1000.0
```

I am using:  `{:bakeware, "~> 0.2.4"}` with Elixir 1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 24)

I develop for windows users, so I can't use Linux here.

### Question

Why cant I make bakeware work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It unfortunately seems that, at the time of writing this post, Bakeware is not being actively maintained. The successor appears to be Burrito:

- https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware/issues/136

However that does not work for windows either:

- https://github.com/burrito-elixir/burrito/issues/111

So I had to go with an alternative, in order to achieve a Windows release. This alternative solution uses Windows shortcuts and seems to work as a short term solution for anyone trying to have an easy launcher for Elixir applications in Windows systems:

- https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-start-phoenix-application-without-showing-terminal-in-windows-11/58893/8?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

If you are from the future and the official Bakeware issue post found a positive resolution, do feel free to update this thread. For the time being however, I am closing this.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell from the information you've provided but I would call your attention to this portion of the Bakeware documentation:

> Bakeware is tested to work in *mingw* environment (emphasis mine)

If you're not trying to *build under mingw* (and I honestly can't tell from what you've provided) that may be the issue. The other thing you want to check it so make sure you've done a `mix deps.get` to insure the bakeware stuff is downloaded.

Comment: I have done a `mix deps.get` and I have followed every instruction from the README file, for Windows machines. It is also important to mention that this used to work in the past, and that it only started to fail recently, after upgrading Elixir and Phoenix to the latest versions. I am not sure why this happens.

Comment: It is also unfortunate that is not tested for Windows 11, the version I recently started using. Following from the docs: "Bakeware is tested to work in mingw environment on Windows 8 and 10."

Comment: Ok, one more thought.  This is in bakeware's mix.exs: `elixir: "~> 1.10",`  Maybe try with Elixir 1.10 and see what happens.  Maybe something changed between 1.10 and 1.15.4 that broke bakeware in some way.

Comment: I cannot use elixir 1.10 on the project, since it depends on features released in v1.15. Furthermore, even after downgrading both elixir and erlang to 1.10 and 23.2 I still couldn't test it, as I `the archive phx_new-1.7.7 requires Elixir "~> 1.14"`. Afaik, this is not testable without any major loops to change the archive.